# mvc controller didnt fire from js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

i need to call the controller action from javascript on imag dragging.

my javascript code is

```
$trash.droppable({

    accept: "#gallery > img",
    // activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var a = ui.draggable;
        var itemsarray = [];
        itemsarray.push(a[0].id);
        // $.getJSON('@Url.Action("SaveImage")', { imageids: itemsarray }, function (mydata) {
        //  alert(mydata);
        // });
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SaveImage")',
            data: JSON.stringify({ imageids: 1 }),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (mydata) {
                alert(mydata);
            }
        });

        deleteImage(ui.draggable);
    }
});
```

In my controller code is,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveImage(int imageids)
{
    GalleryService galService = new GalleryService();
    //galService.UpdatePublishedImages(imageids);
    // return View("Index");
    return Json("test",JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and my view is

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadImage", "Gallery", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<div class="uploadMiddlePanel ">
    <p class="title">
        <img src="Images/event_equation_icon.png" width="25" height="25" alt="event Logo" />
        Gallery Management</p>
    <p class="lightGrayTitle">
        Upload Images</p>
    <div class="UploadContainer">
        <div class="uploadImagePanel" id="gallery">
        @foreach (var src in @imageList)
        { 
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/GalleryImages/" + src.Text)"  id="@Url.Content(src.Value)" alt="Image" class="imagePreview"  />
        }
```

but my js calling function didnt fore my controller, is am missing anything or is any other way to call controller from js.

thanks

Comment: StackOverflow is not a crowd-sourced debugging service.

Comment: Are you sure that that your `drop` function is called, can you put an alert before the ajax call? Because your `$.ajax` call looks fine..

Answer (score 0):

Try calling your controller Action result like this

```
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "@Url.Content("/controllerName/SaveImage/")",
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below things.

1) Your page should not have any jQuery error

2) try to use below direct url
$.ajax({
            url: 'ControllerName/SaveImage',

3) return type of controller

[HttpPost]
public JSONResult SaveImage(int imageids)